# python violin plot regular axis

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot

I want to to a violin plot of binned data but at the same time be able to plot a model prediction and visualize how well the model describes the main part of the individual data distributions. My problem here is, I guess, that the x-axis after the violin plot does not behave like a regular axis with numbers, but more like string-values that just accidentally happen to be numbers. Maybe not a good description, but in the example I would like to have a "normal" plot a function, e.g. `f(x) = 2*x**2`, and at x=1, x=5.2, x=18.3 and x=27 I would like to have the violin in the background.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(10)
collectn_1 = np.random.normal(1, 2, 200)
collectn_2 = np.random.normal(802, 30, 200)
collectn_3 = np.random.normal(90, 20, 200)
collectn_4 = np.random.normal(70, 25, 200)

ys = [collectn_1, collectn_2, collectn_3, collectn_4]
xs = [1, 5.2, 18.3, 27]

sns.violinplot(x=xs, y=ys)

xx = np.arange(0, 30, 10)
plt.plot(xx, 2*xx**2)

plt.show()
```

Somehow this code actually does not plot violins but only bars, this is only a problem in this example and not in the original code though. In my real code I want to have different "half-violins" on both sides, therefore I use `sns.violinplot(x="..", y="..", hue="..", data=.., split=True)`.

Comment: When trying to run your code with Seaborn 0.11, `violinplot` didn't seem to accept the format of `ys`. It expects `'long'` format, so with `ys = np.concatenate([collectn_1, collectn_2, collectn_3, collectn_4]); xs = np.repeat([1, 5.2, 18.3, 27], [len(collectn_1), len(collectn_2), len(collectn_3), len(collectn_4)])` it works.  The weird scaling comes from the `scale=` parameter which defaults to `'area'` and scales the width of the 3 last violins to make their area equal to the first violin (which is very short). Setting `scale='width'` gives more standard-looking violins.

Comment: Thanks, the behaviour really depends a lot on the used seaborn version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that would be hard to do with `seaborn` because it does not provide an easy way to manipulate the artists that it creates, particularly if there are other things plotted on the same Axes. Matplotlib's `violinplot` allows setting the position of the violins, but does not provide an option for plotting only half violins. Therefore, I would suggest using [`statsmodels.graphics.boxplots.violinplot`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.boxplots.violinplot.html), which does both.

```
from statsmodels.graphics.boxplots import violinplot

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
x_col = 'day'
y_col = 'total_bill'
hue_col = 'smoker'

xs = [1, 5.2, 18.3, 27]
xx = np.arange(0, 30, 1)
yy = 0.1*xx**2
cs = ['C0','C1']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(xx,yy)


for (_,gr0),side,c in zip(df.groupby(hue_col),['left','right'],cs):
    print(side)
    data = [gr1 for (_,gr1) in gr0.groupby(x_col)[y_col]]
    violinplot(ax=ax, data=data, positions=xs, side=side, show_boxplot=False, plot_opts=dict(violin_fc=c))

# violinplot above messes up which ticks are shown, the line below restores a sensible tick locator
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator())
```

[image]

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! Interesting how many tools there a to plot violins :)